# is it possible to use between , current_date and subdate functions in hql?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hql

## I want to write such hql query

```
<query name="user.by.date">
    FROM User as u
    where u.Date between subdate(now(), interval 3 day) and now()
```

If it is wrong how can I change ?
where can I see which functions hql support ?
what is the difference between NOW() and CURRENT_DATE() ? 
Is it possible to use CURRENT_DATE() among NOW()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest not to use database specific function like subdate() and now() in your HQL,because HQL is used to make application database independent.Rather you should calculate the 
**subdate(now(), interval 3 day)** and **now()** in java and pass these two value as a parameter in this query,as it very easy to do in JAVA,and finally your query will be like below.

```
<query name="user.by.date">
    FROM User as u
    where u.Date between :prevdate and :currentdate</query>
```

where **prevdate** is equivalent to **subdate(now(), interval 3 day)**,and **currentdate** is equivalent to  **now()**, and both are to be calculated and passed from JAVA code,so it would be easier and more over database independent.

Regarding the difference between **now()** and **current_date()**,**now** gives you date and time while **current_date** gives you only date as output. try below in mysql.

**now():-->**

```
mysql> select now();
+---------------------+
| now()               |
+---------------------+
| 2014-11-19 22:38:15 |
+---------------------+
```

**current_date() -->**

```
mysql> select current_date();
+----------------+
| current_date() |
+----------------+
| 2014-11-19     |
+----------------+
```